# Parse (arbitrary) previously know data from JSON using GO

Tags: json, go, parsing

I have to parse some JSON files.
The problem is: the type of data some field contains varies according some external (already obtained) information.
My question is: how do I perform this using **golang**?
I've looked for a solution for this for hours and tried coming up with one, but I keep getting runtime errors.
Also, I thought the type coercion/casting would work based on [this post](https://www.golangprograms.com/how-to-decode-or-unmarshal-bi-dimensional-array-of-integers.html).

I am quite a newbie regarding that language, so I ask you for not being too harsh answering this.

```golang
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "reflect"
    "unsafe"
)

func main() {
    birdJson := `{
            "blah": "bleh",
            "coord" : [[1,2], [3, 4], [22, 5]]
        }
    `
    var result map[string]interface{}
    json.Unmarshal([]byte(birdJson), &result)
    fmt.Println("result:: ", result)

    c := result["coord"]
    
    cv := reflect.ValueOf(c)
    ct := reflect.TypeOf(c)

    fmt.Println("c value:", cv)
    fmt.Println("c type: ", ct)
    fmt.Println(cv.Interface().([][]int))
}
```

The output:

```sh
result::  map[blah:bleh coord:[[1 2] [3 4] [22 5]]]
c value: [[1 2] [3 4] [22 5]]
c type:  []interface {}
panic: interface conversion: interface {} is []interface {}, not [][]int

goroutine 1 [running]:
main.main()
    /Users/maffei/golab/t.go:27 +0x497
exit status 2
```

Comment: You are not really disclosing what is the variability of your json, but in order to make nested type assertions you can use a library like: https://github.com/Jeffail/gabs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot [type assert](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Type_assertions) nested interfaces with a single expression.

If the dynamic type of `c` is `[][]int`, then you can do `c.([][]int)`.

```golang
var c interface{} = [][]int{{1,2}, {3,4}}
_, ok := c.([][]int) // ok == true
```

However, if the dynamic type of `c` is `[]interface{}`, then you have to do `c.([]interface{})`, you then have to loop over the `[]interface{}` slice and **type assert each element individually**, which, in your case, is another `[]interface{}`, so you'll also need to loop over that and then type assert the individual elements of the nested slice.

Also note that since JSON Numbers are by default unmarshaled as `float64` when the target type is `interface{}`, you'll need to do a [conversion](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Conversions) to `int` to get the result you want

```golang
s1 := c.([]interface{})
out := make([][]int, len(s1))
for i := range s1 {
    if s2, ok := s1[i].([]interface{}); ok {
        s3 := make([]int, len(s2))
        for i := range s2 {
            if f64, ok := s2[i].(float64); ok {
                s3[i] = int(f64) // convert float64 to int
            }
        }
        out[i] = s3
    }
}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/UEdf2VSPg16

Answer (score 4):

It's not really clear what you're trying to do, but you can Unmarshal like this:

```
package main

import (
   "encoding/json"
   "fmt"
)

var birdJson = []byte(`
{
   "blah": "bleh", "coord" : [
      [1,2], [3, 4], [22, 5]
   ]
}
`)

func main() {
   var result struct {
      Blah string
      Coord [][]int
   }
   json.Unmarshal(birdJson, &result)
   fmt.Printf("%+v\n", result) // {Blah:bleh Coord:[[1 2] [3 4] [22 5]]}
}
```

Comment: Preferable answer here imo. When unmarshalling JSON, if possible, using structs will be better than map[string]interface{} and type assertions directly in the code, for readability/maintenance.